# How to use Prepare()?

Tags: sql, go

From the specs of [`Prepare()`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) I thought I can use an `sql` query with Prepare() like this:

```
st, err := db.Prepare("SELECT name FROM pet WHERE name=?", "Fluffy")
```

But I get this error:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\dbtest2.go:25: too many arguments in call to db.Prepare
```

[This](http://goseeds.blogspot.com/2012/05/google-go-and-mysql-tutorial.html) is the only example I could find using `Prepare()` but he does not use queries with parameters. How do I use Prepare()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look further down the example script that you linked to, and you find this...

```
st, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO document (title) VALUES (?)")
if err != nil{
 fmt.Print( err );
 os.Exit(1)
}
st.Exec("Hello Again")
st.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out. This works: `st, err := db.Prepare("SELECT name FROM pet WHERE name=?")`. Is there a more detailed explanation of `Prepare()` in the documentation?